# How to override map merge in scss?

Tags: css, sass

Apologies for the basic question but I am very new to SCSS.
I have this in variables SCSS file

```
$button-colors: () !default;
$button-colors: map-merge(
    (
      "success": #28a745,
      "info": #17a2b8,
      "warning": #ffc107,
      "error": #dc3545,
      "default": #343a40
    ),
    $button-colors
);
```

How can I override the colors in custom file ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this but I like your name xD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily set the value of `$button-colors` variable before `@import` your sass file or at beginning of your code.

About `!default` more info is here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#default-values

This line `$button-colors: () !default;` do nothing when `$button-colors` defined before and when it's not defined before assign empty map to `$button-colors`;
value of `$button-colors` will overwrite default values defined in the `map-marge`.

More information about `map-marge` is here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map

`map-marge` will overwrite 2nd map values on 1st map values for duplicated keys.

```
// overwriting values
$button-colors: (
    "info": #ccc,
    "error": #fff
);

@import <your sass file address or name>
```

or

```
// overwriting values
$button-colors: (
    "info": #ccc,
    "error": #fff
);

$button-colors: () !default;
$button-colors: map-merge(
    (
      "success": #28a745,
      "info": #17a2b8,
      "warning": #ffc107,
      "error": #dc3545,
      "default": #343a40
    ),
    $button-colors
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create another `map` with the same values that you want to override.

```
$button-colors: (
  "success": green,
  "warning": red
);
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8Lh9ovy/)** showing the example

[Also you can read up on the topic of maps here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps)